SilverApp bar is not exceuting function and Guide how do I make it's apearence while loading like the linkdin AppBar
I want my SliverAppBar to behave similarly to the app bar in LinkedIn, but I am not able to achieve the desired results. The onStretchTrigger function is also not executed.
The behaviour I want of my app bar I want to achieve this behavior and functionality
https://github.com/mujtabafrhn2580/best_news_app.git
lib/screens/home.dart   is the file where you will see the SilverAppbar.

Can you provide a minimal code snippet that will reproduce the same error

@Md.YeasinSheikh  Providing minimal code can be very difficult. There are no errors shown in debug console but the onStrechTrigger is not working. I have shared the image of the UI I want to replicate. All of the code which related to the silver AppBar is prensent  in home.dart file

@Md.YeasinSheikh I have shared the Appbar I want to build image. If you want you can reccomend another aproach.
